# Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent with search bots

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, web-crawler

I'm not sure what is happening here but sometimes I get an error message "`Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent`" when trying to set cookies.  From what I can tell it is mostly search bots of some sort.  Do bots have cookies disabled or something?  I can't reproduce it when I disable cookies.  My code below is ran in the controller.  Does it look correct?

```
                var cookie = new HttpCookie(Config.ApiCookie)
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Secure = false,
                    Value = authenticationResponse[SessionKey].ToString()
                };

                if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[Config.ApiCookie] != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                }
```

Comment: Are you possibly flushing any data (i.e. sending response) prior to setting the cookies?  That's what the error message you describe would entail.

Comment: I don't think so, that is why it's baffling me.

Comment: Do you have any asynchronous stuff going on? The only thing that I see here that could do ANYTHING to invalidate is the 'authenticationResponse[SessionKey]'... Try stripping that out setting the value to "test" or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the .Set which is buggy.  I used the code below instead and fixed the issue.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[Config.ApiCookie] != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[Config.ApiCookie].Value = cookie.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
```